# Combining missing and term query in nested document in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have these 3 documents, where `fields` is of type `nested`:

```
{
  "fields": [
    {"field_id": 23, "value": "John Doe"},
    {"field_id": 92, "value": null}
  ]
}

{
  "fields": [
    {"field_id": 23, "value": "Ada Lovelace"},
  ]
}

{
  "fields": [
    {"field_id": 23, "value": "Jack Daniels"},
    {"field_id": 92, "value": "jack@example.com"}
  ]
}
```

I need to search for documents where:

```
(`field_id` = `92` AND `value` is `null`) OR (`field_id` `92` is missing.)
```

Combining a terms and missing query leads to only the document with the `null` value being returned:

```
...
"nested": {
  "path": "fields",
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "bool": {
        "must": [
          {
            "missing": {
              "field": "fields.value"
            }
          },
          {
            "terms": {
              "fields.field_id": [92]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
...
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you mean to say where (`field_id` is `92` **and** `value` is `null`) **or** (`field_id:92` is not present).

Comment: Also is `fields` a [nested field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) or [object field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html)?

Comment: @NishantSaini Yes, that's right. I've edited the post. `fields` is nested (the actual mapping is a lot more complex)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have query for one condition. Lets call this **A**. For second condition check for `fields.field_id: 92` in nested documents. Lets say this is **B**. But your condition is `fields.field_id: 92` should not exist. So to achieve this wrap **B** in `must_not`. i.e. **B'**

What is required is **A *OR* B'**

So the final query will be:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "fields",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "fields.field_id": 92
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "must_not": [
                  {
                    "exists": {
                      "field": "fields.value"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must_not": [
              {
                "nested": {
                  "path": "fields",
                  "query": {
                    "term": {
                      "fields.field_id": 92
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```